# Pivot output isn't as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, transpose

I have data which is already summed and grouped in a dataframe named `df`:

```
| id | segment | region   | points |
|----|---------|----------|--------|
| 90 | Gold    | APAC     | 21     |
| 90 | Silver  | EMEA     | 34     |
| 90 | Bronze  | AMERICAS | 564    |
| 90 | Gold    | EMEA     | 3939   |
| 90 | Silver  | Americas | 989    |
| 90 | Gold    | EMEA     | 43     |
| 90 | Silver  | APAC     | 13     |
| 90 | Bronze  | AMERICAS | 567    |
```

I would like to pivot both `segment` and `region` to columns and then total the points for those columns. The output would look like the below based on the input above:

```
| id | Gold | Silver | Bronze | APAC | EMEA | AMERICAS |
|----|------|--------|--------|------|------|----------|
| 90 | 4003 | 1036   | 1131   | 34   | 4016 | 2120     |
```

What I've tried so far is to convert my dataframe to Pandas and then use the built in `pivot_table` function.

```
import pandas as pd
df_pd = df.toPandas()
pd.pivot_table(df_pd, values = 'points', index=['id'], columns = ['segment', 'region']).reset_index()
```

The code works but the output isn't as expected. Instead of getting totals with each `region` and `segment` as a column, I get two rows of columns. Within the two rows of columns, it appears that `region` is a subgrouping of `segment`. See below (note, numbers don't match due to random numbers being used in the sample data, I'm more concerned about the shape):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with double [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df_pd, values='points', index='id', columns='segment', aggfunc='sum')
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df_pd, values='points', index='id', columns='region', aggfunc='sum')

df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  Bronze  Gold  Silver  AMERICAS  APAC  Americas  EMEA
0  90    1131  4003    1036      1131    34       989  4016
```

In your solution is possible add `sum` per first and per second level of `MultiIndex in columns` with `join`:

```
df3 = pd.pivot_table(df_pd,
                    values = 'points', 
                    index='id', 
                    columns = ['segment', 'region'], 
                    aggfunc='sum')

df = df3.sum(level=0, axis=1).join(df3.sum(level=1, axis=1)).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  Bronze  Gold  Silver  AMERICAS  APAC  EMEA  Americas
0  90    1131  4003    1036      1131    34  4016       989
```